# Ubuntu 16.04 Empty Icons when opening nautilus from a remote folder

Tags: 16.04, ssh, nautilus, gtk

I am logged into a sever using SSH -X, and when I open nautilus in the remote server every single file has the same icon, so I can not differentiate between normal files or folders for example.

[image: Example]

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and a modified GTK theme called paper, could that be the reason ? I tried with other GTK themes and I had the same result.

Comment: Almost certainly it is the theme, do you have the icon pack too? sudo apt install paper-icon-theme https://snwh.org/paper/icons

Comment: it worked installing it in the remote server! Thanks